# Android: How to get a view given an activity inside a normal class?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view

I have a normal class (not an activity). Inside that class, I have a reference to an activity.
Now I want to access a view (to add a child) contained in the layout xml of that activity.
I don't know the name of the layout file of that activity. I only know the ID of the view, which I want to access (for example: R.id.my_view).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the NullPointerException (which you should add to the question), always make sure you've called [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29) in your Activity *before* trying to access a View defined in XML. Example usage:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, somewhere,

```
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) context.findViewById(R.id.group); // In your example, R.id.my_view
```

The reason you need to have called setContentView() is that before it's called, your View(Group) doesn't exist. Because *find*ViewById() is unable to *find* something that doesn't exist, it [returns null](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29).

Comment: Thia seems to be a better explanation. But there is no way for me to control, that setContentView() is called before calling findViewById(). As I said, findViewById lives in a totally separated class.

Comment: You say there is no way for you to control it. I hence kind of have to ask you: where in the life cycle of your Activity do you need to call findViewById()?

Comment: The app which is supported by advertising using Admob Mediation. I need to integrate a custom ad network into Admob mediation. To do this, one needs to write a CustomEvent class. This class is instantiated by Admobs Mediation SDK. That's why I have no control when exactly it is instantiated, and when exactly the findViewById is executed. This class fetches banners asynchronously. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation#android . The class works, fetches banners, but when it tries to add the banner to the viewgroup (LinearLaout obtained by findViewById), I get a NPE.

Comment: The Admob banner is requested in onCreate after findViewById, but asynchronously, with a listener interface. So, as I said, I call Admob after setContentView, but no assumption can be made when Admob instantiates the CustomEvent class, and when the listener receives notification about success or failure to receive the banner.

Comment: Note: The example implemantion in the Admob docs shows how to add Admob as custom network to Admob mediation, which will never be the case. The real world case is that an ad network, which is not supported out-of-the-box, is integrated in Admob mediation. Kinda confusing example.

Comment: You seem to be following my advice regarding order: setContentView(); Admob -> findViewById(); so I don't know what could be causing that NPE :/

Answer (score 3):

As simple as that!

```
View view = activity.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

In case of the Layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_layoutId);
```

And to add the Views:

```
layout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Well then it should be best if you post some code. i´m pretty sure we can figure this one one out! Is your activity null or the result?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your method accept an Activity parameter and then use it to find the view by id.

Ex:

```
public class MyClass{

   public void doSomething(Activity context){
      TextView text=(TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
   }

}
```

Then in your activity:

```
obj.doSomething(YourActivity.this);
```

Comment: Is it possible, that I have to inflate the activiy's layout first? and if so, can anybody provide a code example,

Comment: @mradlmaier, Yes it's possible to get a NPE exception if you use your method for example in a onClickListener.  In this case you should change the argument of the method from this, to ActivityName.this. So, explicitly mention that 'this' to refer to your activity. (I already changed the code)